# CakePHP Query Builder 4.x for SQL INSERT INTO IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, query-builder, cakephp-4.x, slim-4

This [CakePHP Query](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions) isn't using the conditional, `$subQuery` for some reason:

```php
$subQuery = $this->queryFactory->newSelect('table_name')
    ->select(['id'])
    ->where(['id' => $id]);

$query = $this->queryFactory->newQuery()
    ->insert(
        ['id', 'machine', 'logfile', 'updated', 'time']
    )
    ->into('table_name')
    ->values([
        'id' => $id,
        'machine' => $machine['id'],
        'logfile' => $logFile,
        'updated' => $updateDate,
        'time' => $updateTime
    ])
    ->where(function (QueryExpression $exp) use ($subQuery) {
        return $exp->notExists($subQuery);
    });
$query->execute();
```

...it just inserts record even when it exists, but why?

The above code is only part of the required SQL that looks like this:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM table_name
    WHERE id = '$id'
)
    INSERT INTO table_name (id, machine, logfile, updated, time)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
ELSE
    UPDATE table_name
    SET updated = '$var1', time = ' $var2'
    WHERE id = '$id';
```

Comment: The insert query compilation doesn't support conditions. I can't find any documentation about a `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... WHERE` syntax for SQL server. What SQL exactly are you trying to generate?

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I have updated the question with an example of the SQL. My solution so far has been to separate the SQL logic out with php conditionals, but I thought it might be nice to try to complete the statement in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API that would allow to generate such a statement directly, the query builder isn't ment to generate (and execute) such SQL constructs, it can only compile `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` queries, and while the query expression builder can be used to stitch together arbitrary expressions, it will wrap itself and query objects into parentheses (as it is meant for use in query objects), which would be incompatible with what you're trying to build.

So if you want to run such constructs on SQL level, then you either have to write the SQL manually, or create custom expression classes that can build such constructs. In any case you would have to run the SQL manually then.

Here's a very basic quick & dirty example of such a custom expression class:

```php
namespace App\Database\Expression;

use Cake\Database\ExpressionInterface;
use Cake\Database\ValueBinder;
use Closure;

class IfElseExpression implements ExpressionInterface
{
    protected $_if;
    protected $_then;
    protected $_else;
    
    public function if(ExpressionInterface $expression)
    {
        $this->_if = $expression;

        return $this;
    }
    
    public function then(ExpressionInterface $expression)
    {
        $this->_then = $expression;

        return $this;
    }
    
    public function else(ExpressionInterface $expression)
    {
        $this->_else = $expression;

        return $this;
    }

    public function sql(ValueBinder $binder): string
    {
        $if = $this->_if->sql($binder);
        $then = $this->_then->sql($binder);
        $else = $this->_else->sql($binder);

        return "IF $if $then ELSE $else";
    }

    public function traverse(Closure $callback)
    {
        $callback($this->_if);
        $this->_if->traverse($callback);
        
        $callback($this->_then);
        $this->_then->traverse($callback);
        
        $callback($this->_else);
        $this->_else->traverse($callback);

        return $this;
    }

    public function __clone()
    {
        $this->_if = clone $this->_if;
        $this->_then = clone $this->_then;
        $this->_else = clone $this->_else;
    }
}
```

It could then be used something like this:

```php
$notExists = (new \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression())
    ->notExists($subQuery);

$insertQuery = $this->queryFactory->newQuery()
    ->insert(/* ... */)
    //...
    ;

$updateQuery = $this->queryFactory->newQuery()
    ->update(/* ... */)
    //...
    ;

$ifElse = (new \App\Database\Expression\IfElseExpression())
    ->if($notExists)
    ->then($insertQuery)
    ->else($updateQuery);

$binder = new \Cake\Database\ValueBinder();
$sql = $ifElse->sql($binder);

$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$binder->attachTo($statement);
$statement->execute();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Interacting with Statements](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#interacting-with-statements)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks. My own preference is to avoid the requirement to code the value binding explicitly. Using [`where()`](https://api.cakephp.org/4.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#where()), I can do something like this:

```
    $subQuery = $this->queryFactory->newSelect('table_name')
    ->select(['id'])
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->limit(1);
$find = $subQuery->execute()->fetchAll('assoc');

if (!empty($find)) {
    $values = [
        'id' => $id,
        'machine' => $machine,
        'logfile' => $logFile,
        'updated' => $var1,
        'time' => $var2
    ];
    $query = $this->queryFactory->newInsert('table_name', $values);
} else {
    $query = $this->queryFactory->newUpdate('table_name')
    ->set([
        'updated' => $someVar,
        'time' => $someVar2
    ])
    ->where(['id' => $id]);
}
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Well, it is what it is. If you have too much free time you could of course additionally also implement a custom expression execution API that binds the values under the hood ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯